# Java EE webservices, which one?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, rest, soap

I would like to build a Java EE server, that server many different kind of clients. Most of them are mobile clients, but there also can be a browser application.

I would like to choose between REST and SOAP web services. What do you think? Which is better for this approach? Which is more optimal. I would like to see pros/cons if you know.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Please justify why would you like to close this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask "Which should I choose?" falls under this. It's not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SOAP, because REST works only over HTTP, while SOAP can use HTTP,TCP, Named pipes, SMTP, MSMQ etc.